# Is it possible to customize error message "Column does not allow nulls" in a datatable?

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with controls bound to a datatable in VB.net.

When keeping empty a field that should be filled, I'm receiving the error message : **Column does not allow nulls.**

Is it possible to replace this error message string by another one ?

Comment: Do you display the error message? How does the exception handler look like? Please provide some code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers but that's not really my problem.

Everything is about DataTable Object.

My problem is that I don't know where the exception is raised.

Let me explain.

- Assume Column X has AllowDBNull property to false
- And I'm not creating manually a new row that I add to the table

Which means **I'm not using such code**:

```
    Dim NewRow as DataRow = DataTable.NewRow
    NewRom.Item("X") = textbox1.text
    DataTable.rows.add(NewRow)
```

If I was using that code, I would have indeed added the Try/Catch

```
    Dim NewRow as DataRow = DataTable.NewRow
    NewRom.Item("X") = textbox1.text

    try
        DataTable.rows.add(NewRow)
    catch Ex as Exception
        ...
    end try
```

- I'm using a DataNavigator which adds in a hidden manner the new row to be added to the table.
- So, if Column X is empty, he raises by himself the error. **It's not an Exception** to be handled. It's an error displayed at run time. **Programmatically speaking, nothing went wrong at run time**. It seems like DataTable object is designed with this feature and default Error Message.

I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways when it comes to error handling.

You could get your code to throw a custom error alert:
This will throw an alert with the text: `NullCollumContent`

```
    Try
        'your code here
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New System.Exception("NullCollomContent")
    End Try
```

Also as K3rnel31 explained:
This will just show a simple message box to the user

```
    Try
        'your code here 
    Catch ex As Exception
        msgbox("error message here")
    End Try
```

---

You could also use If statements to check the string:

This if checks the length of the string and checks if its equal to 0:

```
    If Not yourString.Length = 0 Then
        'your code here
    else
        'some error handling here
    End If
```

This if checks if your string is equal to "" which basically means an empty string:

```
    If Not yourString Is "" Then
        'your code here
    Else
        'some error handling here
    End If
```

Comment: Edit: I added a "Not" to the first if statement to correct my own mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try
    'your code here to the datatable
    Catch ex As Exception
    msgbox("changed error string here")
    End Try
```